# SimpleInjector Verification process with IIS Express / Visual Studio

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have a proprietary event model built into my solution that has a subscription instantiation process that uses the `GetAllInstances()` method of SimpleInjector to locate all of the subscribers of an event

```cs
public IEnumerable<ISubscriber<T>> GetSubscriptions<T>()
    where T : IEvent
{
    return _container.GetAllInstances<ISubscriber<T>>();
}
```

I am getting a massive difference in performance depending on whether I register all instances of `ISubscriber` or not

this is the code I use to register `ISubscriber`

```cs
internal void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
        typeof(ISubscriber<>),
        AccessibilityOption.PublicTypesOnly,
        (serviceType, implTypes) => 
            container.RegisterAll(serviceType, implTypes),
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    );

    container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ISubscriber<>), 
        typeof(SubscriberTraceDecorator<>));

    container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ISubscriber<>), 
        typeof(SubscriberExceptionDecorator<>));
}
```

When I bootstrap the container without the call to `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` the container verification takes around 11 seconds and returns the  results:

> Configuration Warnings: No warnings detected.
>
> Registrations: Count = 158

However, when I uncomment the call to `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` the container verification takes around 72 seconds and returns the  results:

> Configuration Warnings: 136 container-registered types have been detected that are referenced by 181 components
>
> Registrations: Count = 475

My question is - is this ok or am I doing something wrong here? I am adding more `ISubscriber` classes all the time and start up is now (way) too slow ...

---

**Update**

It seems this is only an issue for a WebAPI project running **inside Visual Studio**. Bootstrapping from a Console Application takes 15 seconds running in Visual Studio. After deploying the WebAPI project to IIS the verification takes 6 seconds.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of SimpleInjector? It enables the user to view all the details of any container verification failures while stepping through the bootstrap code.

Comment: @FacioRatio yes using 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a call to `Verify()`, the Simple Injector container will fallback to a sort of 'just in time' compilation of delegates during the time they are requested for the first time. In that case the container will often build a single delegate for the creation of a whole object graph (that 'root' object + all its direct and indirect dependencies). Since a delegate is built for a whole object graph there is often just a single delegate being compiled.

Compare that to calling the `Container.Verify()` method. When called, this method iterates over all registrations and requests an instance for each registration. This forces the compilation of a delegate for each registration in the container (not only for the root types that are requested directly).

In other words, there is a lot of overhead in calling `Verify` and all this generation and compilation is done at the start-up phase of your application, compared to the just-in-time like behavior you'd otherwise get.

Calling `Verify()` during start-up is not suited for each application. The time it  takes for `Verify()` to complete depends on a lot of factors, such as:

- The power of your machine.
- Whether you're running inside the debugger or not.
- The number of registrations in the container.
- The use of special features. As you have noticed applying decorators can have impact on the compilation process. This especially holds when a decorator contains generic type constraints.

It is good to always call `Verify()` during start-up, until...

Until the configuration gets too big to call `Verify()`. In that case you can do the following:

1. Prevent calling `Verify` when the debugger is attached, since the overhead is here the biggest.
2. Prevent calling `Verify` during start-up in production if it takes too long for the application to start up.
3. Create a unit test that calls into the bootstrapper code to request a configured container instance and let the unit test call `Verify()` on it. This ensures that configuration errors are still caught long before rolling the software out to test, acceptance or production. [A verifiable configuration](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-to#Verifying-Configuration) is very important.